# Alamofire Version 5.2.0 and 5.2.1 both Crash at URL Session delegate

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, alamofire, alamofire-request

I am using latest alamofire version 5.2.1 to make WEB API calls it working perfect with all apis
But when i call api for country list it crash at URL Session Delegate class

```
 open func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive data: Data) {
        eventMonitor?.urlSession(session, dataTask: dataTask, didReceive: data)

        if let request = request(for: dataTask, as: DataRequest.self) {
            request.didReceive(data: data)
        } else if let request = request(for: dataTask, as: DataStreamRequest.self) { //Crash at this line
            request.didReceive(data: data)
        } else {
            assertionFailure("dataTask did not find DataRequest or DataStreamRequest in didReceive")
            return
        }
    }
```

The same request works perfect with normal url session and postman only alamofire cannot handle the response i am attaching screen shot for more detail.

**Response contains 2000 line json but i don't think that's the problem**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello this issue already reported on Alamofire

Contributor said **this issue was fixed by moving to Xcode 11.4.1**

Please check this

https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/3163

Comment: yes so basically alamofire lib is not compatible with xcode 11.1

Comment: It is, Swift 5.1 and 5.2 just have a variety of runtime crashes that Alamofire may hit. Keeping your Xcode up to date should give you the highest chance of avoiding those crashes.